# ¿Como realizar una acción cuando cambia un datePickerUi?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-datepicker

Hoy he traído este pequeña incógnita antes usaba un `<input type="date" ..>` y  esto me permitía obtener el valor cuando el usuario seleccionaba una fecha.

```
$(document).on('change','input[name="date_start"]',function(){
    "use strict";
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Ahora he incluido el **datePickerUi** y el mismo código no funciona como esperaba.

¿Hay que hacer algo diferente?

Este es mi ejemplo:

```js
/*Sencillo*/
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="date_start"]', function() {
  "use strict";
  $('#result').html($(this).val());
});

/*datePickerUi*/
$('.datePickerUi').datepicker({
  firstDay: 1,
  datedefault: "2016/03/11",
  showButtonPanel: true,
  prevText: "<Ant",
  nextText: "Sig>",
  currentText: "Hoy",
  yearRange: "-100:+15",
  monthNames: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
  monthNamesShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
  dayNames: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
  dayNamesShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Juv", "Vie", "Sáb"],
  dayNamesMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sá"],
  weekHeader: "Sm",
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  defaultDate: "2015-12-02",
  closeText: "Cerrar",
  constrainInput: false,
  minDate: "1993-01-18",
  maxDate: "2050-01-18",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $(".datePickerUi").focus();
    $(".datePickerUi").blur();
  }
});
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="date_end"]', function() {
  "use strict";
  $('#result').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for='date_end'>Con DatePickerUI</label>
<input type='text' class='datePickerUi' name='date_end' id='date_end'>

<label for='date_start'>Con Input Date</label>
<input type='date' name='date_start' id='date_start'>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como se explica en la documentación, el evento [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) es invocado cuando el usuario selecciona una fecha.

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  $(".datePickerUi").focus();
  $(".datePickerUi").blur();
  // aqui adentro, haz lo que quieas con dateText
  $('#result').html(dateText);
}
```

Ejemplo:

```js
/* datePickerUi */
var datepicker = $('.datePickerUi').datepicker({
  firstDay: 1,
  datedefault: "2016/03/11",
  showButtonPanel: true,
  prevText: "<Ant",
  nextText: "Sig>",
  currentText: "Hoy",
  yearRange: "-100:+15",
  monthNames: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
  monthNamesShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
  dayNames: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
  dayNamesShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Juv", "Vie", "Sáb"],
  dayNamesMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sá"],
  weekHeader: "Sm",
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  defaultDate: "2015-12-02",
  closeText: "Cerrar",
  constrainInput: false,
  minDate: "1993-01-18",
  maxDate: "2050-01-18",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $(".datePickerUi").focus();
    $(".datePickerUi").blur();
    $('#result').html(dateText);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for='date_end'>Input text con datePickerUi</label>
<input type='text' class='datePickerUi' name='date_end' id='date_end'>

<p id="result"></p>
```

A propósito, existe otro evento para cuando el usuario navega entre los meses/años, llamado [`onChangeMonthYear`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear).

Comment: Fuiste más rápido que yo :)